# Change @RenderBody to point to different View MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

By default, the @RenderBody in _Layout.cshtml in an MVC3 app points to ~/Views/Home/Index.

```
  @RenderBody()
```

Where is this set and how do I change it to point to ~/Views/Account/Logon? Or wherever I want. Thanks

Comment: The `@RenderBody` call will render the content of your actual view.
You should put it wherever you want the view's content to be. It is not pointing to a view, it is simply Rendering the currently requested View. Are you trying to change this to render the `LogOn` view on application start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't point to that view, it merely renders the view that it is given

Your app starts up and goes to the default action on the routing which can be found in `Global.asax`

You can modify that to default to `/Account/LogOn` if you wish

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {

    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        //routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }

    protected void Application_Start() {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I get a 404 when i run the app. If i run the app and then type in http://localhost:64059/Account/LogOn/user, yes im passing in a parameter, my LogOn view appears. How do i fix it so I dont have to do any typing in order for my LogOn view to show

Comment: When your app starts up, it routes to the default action, at that time there is no `user` to pass as a parameter

Comment: Update your question with your LogOn action so I can see how you are passing your `user`

Comment: *Update* I changed my URl with parameters to db cause i changed the id param to db. Now the app starts but when i pass in a db param like http://localhost/?db=database, db is null when it hits the controller

Comment: That's a new problem you might want to start a new question for that after researchin... and how are you passing a db as a param??

Comment: I'll open a new question. Thanks

Comment: you cannot pass db as a parameter in your URL, you need to define that logic in the LogOn action method. If the LogOn action method is now firing then this question has been answered.

Comment: @user1202717 once you post I'll have a look, it should be very simple to fix

Answer (score 1):

RenderBody doesn't point by default to `~/Views/Home/Index`. It renders the view that was returned by the controller action that was executed. And since in your Global.asax in the routing definition the default action is configured to be Index, it is this view that is rendered.

So all you have to do is modify your routing configuration so that the default action is Logon on the Account controller:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Now when you navigate to `/`, the LogOn action of the `Account` controller will be executed which itself will render the `~/Views/Account/LogOn.cshtml` view.

Comment: I made the change and when I run the app, I get a 404. If i run the app and then type in http://localhost:64059/Account/LogOn/user, yes im passing in a parameter, my LogOn view appears. How do i fix it so I dont have to do any typing in order for my LogOn view to show

Comment: That's weird. If you made the change and you have only this route setup when you navigate to `http://localhost:64059/`, this should execute the LogOn action on the Account controller (assuming this action exists).

Comment: It does exist. My code looks exactly like yours, i just changed id to db and thats it.

Comment: Well, this code works perfectly fine for me when I create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application and make the change. So ... I really don't see how I can help any further without having more details about your application.

Comment: I changed the id param to db but i changed it in one place. I changed it in {controller}/{action}/{db} and now it works

Comment: db is not a parameter that you can pass

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@RenderPage` instead. Follow this [link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=636) for more information.